# Golang Time.Sub returns hours, mins, seconds - how to get it in days or months?

Tags: date, go, time

In Golang, I am trying to find out the difference between a given `time.Time` value and the current `time.Time` value using `time.Sub` and my result looks like this -

```
4691h42m17.1831189s
```

Is it possible to make it return the number of days or months without performing any mathematical manipulations on this value and just using the `time` package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not possible. The type [`Duration`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration) that is returned by `time.Sub` is limited to hours:

> There is no definition for units of Day or larger to avoid confusion across daylight savings time zone transitions.

Comment: So the only way is to parse it as a string, extract the hours part and convert it to days? :(

Comment: @GauravOjha Don't parse it. Duration is actually `int64`, use duration.(int64) to get nanoseconds. Yet conversion is not trivial.

Comment: Thank you! The comment made by @icza is also helpful in this context.

Comment: @GrzegorzŻur The proper syntax to convert a Duration to int64 is `int64(duration)` , not a type assertion.

Comment: The duration type probably already has the method you're looking eg: `duration.Hours()` https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration.Hours